# Is this meta site going to get merged with meta.stackoverflow.com at some point?

Tags: discussion, meta

NOTE: I'm not saying that we don't need this meta site during the beta phase - I think it will be vital.

However, once the site goes public a lot of the questions that will be asked will have already been asked in relation to the other sites. So rather than duplicate a lot of the information here wouldn't it be better to gave it all in one place?

The only (!) drawback I can see is that the current culture on (the one true) Meta might put people off.

Comment: But then I wonder if the name meta.stackoverflow.com is still valid, once it starts to count for every stack EXCHANGE site...?!?

Comment: @Ivo - is it valid when we have Super User and Server Fault anyway?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: meta.stackoverflow uses that name because it is the name of the company.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This meta site (meta.webapps) is for question about the operation and administration of *this*  site (webapps.stackexchange.com) *specifically.* Any questions about the Network or the engine should be redirected to http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

So, no. Meta.Webapps will not be merged or removed. It has its place in the continuing operation of this site, even long after beta.

Comment: Will there be a (prominent) link to *the* Meta for more general questions?

Answer (score 4):

Each StackExchange site should have it's own Meta site for helping drive the community.

The cultures of the users on the various sites will likely end up being very different than that from StackOverflow (once the sites expand outside of the geek realm).

It makes sense that there could be one site for issues concerning the StackExchange/StackOverflow engine, however.