# "What are some sites?" or "Let's make a list of X!" type questions

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, private-beta

Here is a question

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/620/what-are-good-qa-websites-out-there

entitled "What are good Q&A websites out there ?"

To me this seems to have nothing at all to do with web applications. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 8):

This is another case of the "List of X" problem. Our engine is absolutely brilliant at surfacing these questions, and they can have *some* utility ... but they're not really what we want -- they tend to be polls and copy-pasted content, not original contributions.

In the worst case they're like the ["Favorite Programming Cartoon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) question. In the best case they're like the ["New Programming Jargon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined) question.

The rule I've used in the past in these grey areas is ...

> can an average user learn something from this question?

... which is even murkier here. If it's just a list of products with no explanation, then no. If it contains detailed information about the features and *how* they can be used, and *why* you might want to choose one over the other, then yes.

"How?" and "Why?" has more lasting value than a bunch of product-feature bullet points, no matter how extensive.

Comment: Now I know why a certain someone suspects that you're a vampire.  What are you doing answering questions at 3:48 AM?

Comment: @raven That's ok he's never online from 8am EST - 4pm EST (err, 5am PST - 1pm PST).

Comment: please see my [question here](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/354/detailed-list-questions-and-cw).

Answer (score 1):

At least two people agree with you. It's currently got two down-votes and one vote to close as "off topic".

It's certainly a borderline question - I'm still sitting on the fence.

There are currently two questions here discussing "off-topicness" [here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-is-off-topic-for-the-web-apps-site) and perhaps a more relevant one asking to define the [difference between web apps and web sites](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/whats-the-difference-between-a-website-and-a-web-app).

Personally I think it's going to be hard to tell the difference between and application and a site in a lot of cases. A Q&A "site" is such a case. It's fairly certain that such a site is actually an application, but and end user might not see it as such and as far as they're concerned it's a "web site".

We need to be flexible and fair.

Comment: At least one person agrees with me, since I downvoted it and voted to close it as well.