# What should we do with WordPress questions and how tag them?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, private-beta, public-beta

Users are starting to ask questions about WordPress.

If they ask about **WordPress.com** I think they are on topic, but what if they ask about **plug-ins** that currently are not supported by WordPress.com services?

If we decide to allow only question about WordPress.com do you think that could be a good idea to rename tag [wordpress](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) to [wordpress.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com) starting from now?

Comment: Related [Are questions about self-installed web apps on or off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370/88163)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree -- this is a site for end users, where the work is done "in the cloud", not by them, and certainly not on their own servers.

If you are hosting your own site, I believe it should go to Pro Webmasters (or the WordPress public <strike>beta</strike> site).

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com for WordPress developers and administrators

Comment: I'm sure the WordPress guys are going to be MathOverflow/Server Fault on these questions and close any that seems too easy

Comment: The wordpress proposal is now in beta.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, I will mention your concern. `;)`

Comment: [wordpress.se] is out of beta and they suggest to try WebApps for questions about wordpress.com. More details on http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/4076/88163

Answer (score 16):

I personally think this is getting a little too segmented and pedantic.  Someone who hosts their own instance of Wordpress is not necessarily a "pro webmaster."  Most hosting companies allow you to buy a domain and hosting services, then setup your own wordpress blog in one or two clicks.  Adding plugins to Wordpress is not difficult or a "power user" type of function.  The Wordpress admin is basically a web-app itself.  I don't see the point in segmenting questions about the limited wordpress.com hosting vs. a self-hosted wordpress instance.

I think these stack exchange sites need to be careful to not segment the communities too much.  In my humble opinion, the biggest reason that Stackoverflow works so well is because it's a community for programmers across all languages.  You get one large user-base, and they can see questions across all languages, and they can choose which questions to ignore or view.  It would not work as well if you had a C# site, a separate Java site, etc.  In my opinion the large user base is the key to success.  Sure, I could ask this question on the Wordpress-specific stack exchange, but my chances of finding a user that is familiar with both Wordpress and Last.fm goes down, compared to asking in a more general site like this one.  If I ask on "Pro Webmasters," the question will probably be closed as off-topic, because it's not related to professionally administering a web site.

I think the question at hand is appropriate for "webapps" because it's regarding a web app (wordpress), which has a web-based admin app, which allows to install plugins related to other web apps without any coding whatsoever.  I originally asked this question on superuser.com, and it was closed there, so I thought I'd try asking on the "webapps" stack exchange, but now I'm being redirected to other yet-to-be-created stack exchange sites.  I'm losing interest in finding the exact correct home for this question, and I think most users unfamiliar with the "stack exchange engine" are going to be put off by having their question redirected and debated in this fashion.

I guess my main question here is why must this question be closed on webapps?  Is it really that damaging or unfit for this particular community?

Comment: In my opinion the risk is that WebApps become a plug-in research site, what I don't like. I think also that when Twitter, Facebook, Google Apps, Flickr, etc. are involve that are web apps used by million of users, the large user-base will not be a problem for WebApps

Comment: Further, the WordPress.org version of wordpress is offered as a webapp that can be automatically installed and upgraded on individual hosting services. With the latest release it is entirely possibly to add, delete, and install plugins all without ever using FTP or editing code at all. The decision over at SO to include "wordpress" as off-topic has caused good questions to get blackballed too soon, in my opinion. And, I'll add, I hope that webapps does not suffer a similar fate.

Comment: So glad that capital_P_dangit() isn't enabled here...

Comment: +1 "I think these stack exchange sites need to be careful to not segment the communities too much."

Answer (score 5):

Frankly if they are asking more complex questions or more specific questions like about plugins or themes I think **they should be sent to [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)**. Sending them to WordPress answers will get them lot more and a lot better answers because [WA](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is populated with self-hosted WordPress experts and enthusiasts.

JMTCW anyway.

Comment: +1 I wish we could migrate questions there.

Comment: @Simon: For the record, this is now possible (but maybe only for moderators?). We already got some of your old unanswered WP questions.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a question about my WordPress.org site today.  It was immediately closed as off topic, but then later re-opened.

[How to display RSS feed link on Wordpress site?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5293/how-to-display-rss-feed-link-on-wordpress-site)

I had originally posted the question over at Super User.  They said it was off topic and suggested I might post it over here.

WordPress is a form of web application.  Whether I'm hosting it or it is running on Wordpress.com seems beside the point.

Perhaps the distinction is whether I'm **using** a Web Application or **administering** it?

It seems to me that as a WordPress administrator, I'm still a form of *user* of the web application.

The FAQ states that this stack exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications.  It seems that this would be the ideal site for me to post questions pertaining to "using" my WordPress site.

To answer the original question, I believe that questions related to the use of wordpress should be on-topic here.

Comment: Yes I spoke with some other users and decided to revert my decision and leave these questions open for now. As you can see from this discussion definition was still in order. For me the initial  difference in using wordpress.com and wordpress.org is one allows you to administer more than the other. Because there was no clear definition (not enough community members speaking up) yet I decided to stay with the wordpress.com questions only. Now all are allowed in the hopes the community will handle them accordingly. I apologize for the swift hammer.

Answer (score 1):

[Wordpress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is out of beta and they suggest to try WebApps for questions about wordpress.com. From https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic:

> regarding WordPress.com support issues
>   ...
>   - questions regarding the use of WordPress.com - try WebApps

I think that we should make [wordpress](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) a synonymous of [wordpress.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com).

---

At this time we have 150 questions with [wordpress*]:
*(questions could use one or more of this tags)*

- [wordpress](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) 112 questions
- [wordpress.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com) 45 questions, no tag wiki
- [wordpress.com-themes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com-themes) 2 questions
- [wordpress.com-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com-tags) 2 questions

Answer (score 0):

Any and all wordpress.com-type questions will probably be referred here from the WordPress proposal as they are off-topic there. Like-wise, if you know anything at all about wordpress, you will know that it is more than what you see on wordpress.com. A lot more!

**Update:** There is a related discussion there: https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52