# Please, reopen my question or give me a good reason on why it was closed

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

Can someone tell me who marked [my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120886/21486) as off-topic, closed it and why?

I just want to say that the closure given reason is a complete misunderstanding.

I am asking about a out-of-the-box feature of Gmail [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120886/21486). My [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/120886/21486) has absolutely **nothing** to do with creating or developing a web application. Someone took all things very wrong here, sorry.

(at least give it a good reason, please)

**EDIT**: The question is no deleted so I am providing a screenshot of it, as requested:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Do the moderators plan to close most questions on this site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/7584)

Comment: The answer was deleted, and so we can't see it. If you can see it, could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Relevant meta discussion post by a community manager who asked the community: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is on-topic. It is about why Gmail displays some warning and how to avoid that:

> What can I do about it? Is there any known source of Gmail's "knowledge" or some official ratings which leads Gmail to such decision (on whether to display such warining or not)? Or is it -- as always -- some internal, unpublished Google's algorithm and I must learn to live with this.

It's not about WordPress development. It's not about administering websites. It's about the Gmail website, which is on-topic here.

Since the question got removed by the automated deletion script as a result of its closure by a moderator, I voted to undelete.

---

To reply to arguments made by the other answer:

> If you are no longer interested in the question consider you might delete it, as it doesn't help anyone that a question like this one as its current state stay sit there for years without any progress update

The question allows other users who may know the answer to post the answer. There's already a script to automatically delete questions with no answers. If you disagree with that script, you can [raise the issue on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179).

> You might remove the mention that you are the sender of the links and remove wordpress. Questions should not include chitchat and tags should be about what is being asked not about the words included in the question.

That's really not a reason to close. Just make an edit if that's really an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Tl;Dr: Your question needs to be improved or deleted

1. You might remove the mention that you are the sender of the links and remove [wordpress](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress). Questions should not include chitchat and tags should be about what is being asked not about the words included in the question.
2. If you are no longer interested in the question consider you might delete it, as it doesn't help anyone that a question like this one as its current state stay sit there for years without any progress update. It looks as a *broken-window*.
   As it's clear that you have already read the comments, I will purge them as they are no longer required.

---

The question is tagged with [wordpress](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress). Since the early days was said that questions about Worpress are off-topic here. In the question it's mentined that the with the emails having the links with the problem come from a Wordpress site managed by you and in the comments from several years ago was recommended that change the URL protocol from http to https.

Regarding the close reason it textually says

> It is a question about creating/developing a web application.

This close reason is also used for questions related to administering websites. In this case was used because, since you are the sender of the emails you can fix this from the source have doing changes to your website. Doing does changes are site adminitration tasks which are off-topic to be asked here, so it doesn't make sense to ask you to edit the question or add a progress update regarding this.

P.S. Next time that you ask a question, before asking the question please search this site and the resources from the corresonding web app thoroughly. In the quesion include what you tried to fix the problem by yourself, what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Reference

- [What should we do with WordPress questions and how tag them?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/162/88163)
- [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685/88163)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. However your answer seems to be speaking in similar way as the close reason, so I tend to believe that there is still an open misunderstanding here. The only message that my question carries (should carry) is as simple as: "Gmail spam filters are working incorrectly. They're tagging a links to _some website_ incorrectly as suspicious. Is there anything I can do to train them or change the behaviour of these filters?". Nothing more, nothing else.

Comment: You can totally forget that this is my own website or Wordpress. I'd ask the same question in any scenario -- if Gmail would be tagging _any_ link to _any_ website incorrectly as suspicious, I'd ask exactly the same question. Asking, how to stop this or change this (train the filters), if that possible. That is the entire message that my question carries and that is why I still don't understand, why it was treated as off-topic. Thank you.

Comment: Briefly: Questions that **need to be improved** might be **closed** (not deleted), in contrast questions that are *blatantly off-topic* are *deleted* and the OP might get a ban / account deletion *immeatiately*. Your question **needs to be improved**. If you are no longer interested in that question you might deleted it.

Comment: On contrary: I would like to answer this question, as I have a solution to the described problem. Can't do that until question is closed.

Comment: @trejder In such case, please edit the question to make it a good fit for this site. This is required because self-answered questions should meet the quality standards too.