# Are Questions about media-wiki on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Today morning I needed an answer to a issue I was having with media-wiki.  Before posting it, I was not sure if I should post it here, or post it on Webmasters.se. That's why I checked for the tags on both sites. WebApps.SE had 69 questions tagged [media-wiki](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki), while WebMasters.se has 56 questions tagged [media-wiki](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediawiki)

Hence I assumed that media-wiki questions were on-topic here, and posted this question:
[How to make the 'All pages' as the Main Page in Mediawiki?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44900/how-to-make-the-all-pages-as-the-main-page-in-mediawiki?noredirect=1#comment35690_44900)

Soon I got comments saying that this question was off-topic. I have a few more questions about media-wiki and hence want to know if these questions would be allowed here, or closed as off-topic.

If it is off-topic, maybe the other 68 questions tagged media-wiki should also be closed, so as to avoid confusion.

There has been one related discussion on this topic: [Are questions about self-installed web apps on or off topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/are-questions-about-self-installed-web-apps-on-or-off-topic)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Web Apps is for **users** of web applications.

Media-wiki is a web application.

Therefore, if you are asking about the **use** of media-wiki then the questions are definitely on topic. This can include the end user or the admin user of course.

However, if you are asking about the **installation** of media-wiki then the questions are off topic. [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the official stamp of approval!