# Are questions about creating websites on- or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope, private-beta

*NOTE: I ask this question to give you a solid example of the type of questions we should be talking about during this beta.*

Is this question on- or off-topic: [Can anyone recommend a free web hosting site?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/307/can-anyone-reccomend-a-free-web-hosting-site)

It was my understanding that this site would be about *using* the web. Not *creating* or administering web sites. But related to my question about [what is a Web App](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/whats-the-difference-between-a-website-and-a-web-app), these are the things we should be decided here.

<sup>*Sorry @Nifle, I don't mean to be picking on your question.*</sup>

Comment: What about questions about web services provided by web apps?

Comment: @Marc: It's all up for discussion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions about creating websites are definitely off topic for Web Apps.

They would be a good fit for [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) , however!

Comment: The question is more about hosting rather than creating though.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that questions about hosting like that would be better off in [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: And there it would likely get closed to, because it's not really about your computer, but some remote server you have zero control over

Comment: while I appreciate the sentiment (they are in fact off topic here) they aren't really a fit for SU either.. but how about some Pro Webmasters! http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters?referrer=BndrLMp5KJk1

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is "yes" :)

In some cases it is on-topic, e.g. Are there any good web apps / sites where I can build my own website? The answers could be things like Google Sites / Blogspot etc, which are web-based apps and just happen to have the purpose of creating other web content.

In some cases it would be off-topic, e.g. What good hosting companies for my new website are there? In this case, there is nothing about web-based apps being used, just something web-based being produced.

To be on topic it has to make USE of web-based applications and the question should centre around the application itself (i.e. not the platform etc). That's how I see it anyway - what do others think?

Comment: I think it's 95% off topic for web apps; the whole *point* of web apps is you don't have to configure or think about anything, all the magic is done in the cloud.

Comment: We have not accepted "are there any good" or "what good {X} are there" list recommendation questions for a long time.

Comment: @ale At the time of the answer, I believe they weren't off topic. But the point OP makes is valid, if a webapp is used to create webapps, then they're on-topic like  for example: Google-sites, as OP points out.