# How to define a web app?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define “web application”](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/define-web-application)

What essentially defines a web app? Are all useful websites web apps?

As examples, is Google search a web app? G-mail? Wikipedia?

Comment: You want to read up more on [Web App](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_app) and [Web Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application)

Comment: Duplicate and belongs on meta

Answer (score 2):

I think that in one phrase it can be defined as an application that you run and access through your browser. 
I guess that the difference with a "basic" website would be that the website aim is mostly to display information and not really interact with the user.
Of course the definition is not really precise. For some application it is quite obvious (as for most of Google products, facebook...), but for others it may depend on your own interpretation.

I'd cite some definitions found on websites :

- **this site's FAQ:**

> Web Apps - Stack Exchange is for
>   expert and advanced users of web
>   applications, so if your question
>   generally covers …
>
> ```
> * Gmail
> * Facebook
> * Twitter
> * Google
> ```
>
> … or any other website which behaves
>   like an application, then you're in
>   the right place to ask your question!

- **Wikipedia is a little more generic :**

> A web app is an application that uses
>   technologies such as Javascript, CSS
>   and HTML5 and is executed in a web
>   browser. The application can be
>   run directly from a website, or, if it
>   uses the HTML 5 Offline Application
>   Cache and Web Storage, can be
>   downloaded and installed locally, for
>   offline use.

or

> In system software, a web application
>   is an application that is accessed
>   over a network such as the Internet or
>   an intranet. The term may also mean a
>   computer software application that is
>   hosted in a browser-controlled
>   environment (e.g. a Java
>   applet) or coded in a
>   browser-supported language (such as
>   JavaScript, combined with a
>   browser-rendered markup language like
>   HTML) and reliant on a common web
>   browser to render the application
>   executable.