# What are the components of a Web app?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a website and a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/whats-the-difference-between-a-website-and-a-web-app)

I was wondering whether someone could provide an in-depth definition of what the web-app is and what are the components. Is it simply a front-end HTML with some framework behind that translates your code to JavaScript/AJAX?