# Is question on how to use a website's in a specific function opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

The question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73368/is-reddit-a-good-place-to-ask-questions I asked has been put on hold as primarily opinion-based. So I come to the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and I see that my question is [on the scope of Web App](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/whats-the-difference-between-a-website-and-a-web-app/756#756). I don't think this question is opinion-based because you still need to give some example to prove your point, but I agree that it is on the line.

Comment: You're asking if a website is good for asking questions. How is that not opinion based?different people will have different opinions on why it may /may not be good

Comment: cause people need to give example to prove their point

Comment: ergo, it becomes an opinion post.

Comment: if so, then where should I ask these question?

Comment: Doubt it'll be ontopic for any site on [se]. You can drop by [chat] rooms and check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're asking about how 'good' a specific question will be perceived. That's not a question on how to use a website in a specific function.

if you'd asked "How do I ask a question or how do I create a poll on reddit" - then it's on-topic.

Furthermore you state

> Please give an example to prove your point.

which is an further invitation to request for more opinions and hence was closed